# else if command not executing task

Tags: javascript, css

I want to toggle the color of the background based on whether or not a div has the display attribute set to block or none.

So far what I have is

```
if(document.getElementById("welcome").style.display="block"){
        mpage.style.background="rgba(27, 27, 27, .88)";

    }
        else if (document.getElementById("welcome").style.display="none"){
            mpage.style.background="rgba(255, 255, 255, .44)";
            }
```

The only reason I made it that far is because I found another post on here attempting to do something similar and this is the best I could form it.  I used a syntax validator to check the code and it came back ok, nothings popping up in the console, yet the color doesn't change when I trigger the "welcome" div to toggle to "display:none;".

Comment: did you set any type of `display` property of `#welcome` in `CSS` initially??

Comment: Please update the question with `CSS` code as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(document.getElementById("welcome").style.display=="block"){
        mpage.style.background="rgba(27, 27, 27, .88)";

    }else if (document.getElementById("welcome").style.display=="none"){
        mpage.style.background="rgba(255, 255, 255, .44)";
       }
```

using a single `=` assigns the value to the display then checks if it's `true` and it always be true, but using `==` only checks the value, using `===` checks the value and the type

**UPDATE**
You can't check the display property if it's given with the stylesheet, this only works if the style is written inline the div tag

ex:

```
<div id="welcome" style="display:none;">some content</div>
```

Comment: ok I just tried this and it didn't work.  I even tried with === as well.

Comment: @DaMightyOptiq this is because your style is not inline style, you are giving the style in your style-sheet, try setting the display inline with the tag

Comment: so change my css to inline instead of block?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(document.getElementById("welcome").style.display="block"){
                                                   ^
```

to

```
if(document.getElementById("welcome").style.display=="block"){
                                                   ^^
```

Otherwise, using single `=`, you just change the style instead of checking if display is "block"

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(document.getElementById("welcome").style.display="block"){
```

To

```
if(document.getElementById("welcome").style.display=="block"){
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use equality operator instead of assignment operator
For more info [visit this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality_())